# Creating Python Class for Transforming Non-Alphanumeric Characters to Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class in Python that transforms non-alphanumeric characters to a dash for a list of strings.

For example, we have the following list:  `inventory_list_1 = ['ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales', 'JKLEH : SC ; CLIENT : Record Number; old Sales']`

And we want the end result to be:  `inventory_list_2 = ['ABCDE-CE-CUSTOMER-AccountNumber-NewSales', 'JKLEH-SC-CLIENT-RecordNumber-oldSales']`

I tried to create the following class, but it did not work.  How does one create a Python class to transform non-alphanumeric characters to a dash for a list of strings?  And how does one execute the class to transform `inventory_list_1` to `inventory_list_2`?

```
class clean_data:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list
    def transform_data(self):
        for string_item in self.list:
            return re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '-', string_item)
```

`print (clean_data(inventory_list_1))`

Answer (score 1):

Any function can execute return statement only once. In your approach, you are trying to traverse all the list items and then returning each modified item. But as mentioned above, only one return statement will get executed, and hence only the first modified element is being returned instead of the whole list.

To return all the modified elements, create a new list appending all the modified element and then return the new list from the function.

```
def class clean_data:
    def __init__(self, list1):
         self.list1 = list1
    def transform_data(self):
         retList =[]
         for string_item in self.list1:
             retList.append(re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '-', string_item))
    return(retList)

inventory_list_1 = ['ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales', 'JKLEH : SC ; CLIENT : Record Number; old Sales']
print (clean_data(inventory_list_1).transform_data())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `__repr__` for your class.

```
import re

class clean_data:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list
    def transform_data(self):
        temp = []
        for string_item in self.list:
            temp.append(re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '-', string_item))
        return temp
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.list)

inventory_list_1 = ['ABCDE : CE ; CUSTOMER : Account Number; New Sales', 'JKLEH : SC ; CLIENT : Record Number; old Sales']
temp = clean_data(inventory_list_1)
inventory_list_2 = temp.transform_data()
print(inventory_list_2)
```